# Count data using Laravel eloquent query from multiple table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have 3 table 'Admins', 'Agent', 'Books'

Admin can add multiple Agents, Agents can add multiple books.

Now I need to count the book for a single Admin. (Every table has the proper foreign key).

How can I achieve this?

**My code**

```
//In Controller
$data = Admin::latest()->withCount('datacount')->get();

//In Admin.php
public function datacount(){
  return $this->hasMany(Agent::class, 'adminId', 'id');
}

//In Agents.php
public function datacount(){
  return $this->hasMany(Books::class, 'AgentId', '???');
}

//In Book.php
public function datacount(){
  return $this->belongsTo(???::class, 'AgentId', '???');
}
```

??? - I don't know which Id or class need to pass

Can anyone help to solve this issue, please?

Comment: First of all, Laravel Models, by being an indirect extension of the `Builder` class, already have a `count()` method; you probably shouldn't use that are your method name. `public function agents()`, `public function books()`, etc. That all being said, you may need to use this package: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep to accomplish this. Laravel has a `hasManyThrough()` relationship, but I don't remember if that works via `hasMany()->hasMany()` or not.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, I am just writing an example here, in my application I use a custom name instead of count. @TimLewis

Comment: Ok sweet  So yeah, aside from that part of my comment, if you define them correctly as 2 `hasMany()` relationships, then you can either try a `hasManyThrough()` for `Admin` > `Agent` > `Book`, or if that doesn't work, give the linked package a try. Documentation for `hasManyThrough()`: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through